# Why I have this error when try to add converter to ResourceDictionary?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, converters

I try to add converter to ResourceDictionary because I need to use it, but when only I add declariation an error occur when I run the app.

This is how add converter declaration:

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"   
xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity" 
xmlns:Command="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.WP71"
xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:Sample.Utility.Converters">

<converters:BoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisibilityConverter"/>
```

And this is a error I received

```
{System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: The type 'BoolToVisibilityConverter' was not found. [Line: 17 Position: 44]
   at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri resourceLocator)
   at Sample.App.InitializeComponent()
   at Sample.App..ctor()}
```

I event tried to add the converter to , but the result as the same.

Can any help me with my problem, please ?

---

this is code of my Converter

```
public class BoolToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    #region IValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool visible = (bool)value;

        return (visible ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed);

    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Visibility vis = (Visibility)value;
        switch (vis)
        {
            case Visibility.Collapsed:
                return false;
            case Visibility.Visible:
                return true;
        }
        return null;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Can you show Converter's code?

Comment: And that converter class is actually in the `Sample.Utility.Converters` namespace?

Comment: Can you try to move xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:Sample.Utility.Converters" to your PhoneApplicationPage or Application definitione (at the top) or directly to converters:BoolToVis xmlns:...?

Comment: It's working when I add this to any Page or UserControl, but it doesn't work neither in ResourceDictionary nor App.xaml

Comment: Do you havy any idea how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

To have a resource dictionary available globally in your app, you need to merge it like this in your `App.xaml`:

```
<Application x:Class="Sample.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/uri/to/resource_dictionary.xaml"/>
      </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```